# React registraion

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I`m new in react, and I get problem with registration:

http.hook.js:17 POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Error: Что-то пошло не так :(, попробуйте снова
    at http.hook.js:21
    at async registerHandler (Registration.js:24)

code http.hook.js :

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react';

export const useHttp = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);


    const request = useCallback( async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {

            if (body) {
                body = JSON.stringify(body);
                headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            }

            const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers});
            const data = await response.json();

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(data.message || 'Что-то пошло не так :(');
            };

            setLoading(false);

            return data;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            setLoading(false);
            setError(e.message);
            throw e;
        }
    }, [])

    const clearError = useCallback( () => setError(null), []);

    return { loading, request, error, clearError }
}
```

and code Registration.js without front-end:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHttp } from '../hooks/http.hook';
import { useMessage } from '../hooks/message.hook';

export const Registration = () => {
    const message = useMessage();
    const {loading, error, request, clearError} = useHttp();
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        nick: '', email: '', password:''
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(error);
        message(error);
        clearError();
    }, [error, message, clearError]);

    const changeHandler = event => {
        setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const registerHandler = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await request('/api/auth/register', 'POST', {...form});
            console.log('Data', data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your server-side.
HTTP response code 500 means that the server encountered an unexpected condition.

Test your endpoint by curl or XHR request.

Also maybe you send not valid data.